# srand function in perl not giving correct range of values

Tags: perl

I am trying to use srand function in perl but seems that its not setting the seed value every often

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
srand(45);
$int = rand(50);
print "random integer is $int\n";

[root@localhost cookbook]# perl p2.7.pl 
random integer is 17.8465963028886
```

Shouldn't the random number be something between 45 and 50?

Comment: In order to _format_ code, indent it four spaces. The code is highlighted based upon the tag too.

Comment: You can also highlight the code after pasting it and press ctrl-k.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [srand](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html) ***seeds*** the random number generator. Random numbers in most programming languages aren't truly random, but that's okay for most purposes. Setting a seed will allow the random number sequence to repeat over and over. From the Perldoc:

> [T]here are a few situations where programs are likely to want to call `srand`. One is for generating predictable results, generally for testing or debugging. There, you use `srand($seed)`, with the same `$seed` each time.

Here's a sample program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables

use feature qw(say);

srand 10;
for my $count ( (1..6) ) {
    say rand 10;
}
```

Every time I run it, I get:

```
$ test.pl
8.78851122762175
7.95806622921617
4.80827281057042
5.25673258208322
4.59162474505394
9.45475794360377
```

Over and over. That's because I'm using the same *seed* each time, allowing the random number function to repeat over and over. This can be useful in testing.

Get rid of that `srand 10` line, and the program generates a different sequence of random numbers each time.

According to Perldoc [rand](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html):

> Returns a random fractional number greater than or equal to 0 and less than the value of EXPR, [the argument given]. EXPR should be positive.

It continues:

> Apply `int()` to the value returned by `rand()` if you want random integers instead of random fractional numbers. For example, `int(rand(10))` returns a random integer between `0` and `9` , inclusive.

So, `rand 50` returns a value between 0 and 50 (but not 50). Saying, `int( rand 50 )` will return an *integer* between 0 and 49. If I want a number between 45 and 50, I would have to first decide if 50 should be one of the numbers I want. If it is, I need a range of six numbers (45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50). Thus, I want to use `int( rand 6 )` to give me an integer between 0 and 5. Then I want to add 45 to that to give me a range of 45 to give me a range of 45 to 50:

```
say 45 + int( rand 6 );
```

Comment: `(45..50)[ rand 6 ]` would also work and would be similar to the Perl6 construct `(45..50).roll` (`.pick` also works in this instance). In this case I would advise against it in Perl5 as it uses more memory and is likely slower, but it can be useful if you are choosing from a non-continuous range such as `('A',2..10,'J','Q','K')[ rand 13 ]`

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't the random number be something between 45 and 50?

No. `srand` sets the seed of the random number generator (and I suggest you not modify the seed if you don't know what you're doing), it does nothing to the range. It sounds like you really wanted something like

```
$int = 45 + rand(5);
```